# Can't control layer's canvas size with KineticJS

Tags: kineticjs

I'm using KineticJS and I want to use many small layers to gain performance for intensive drawings, but I found out (with firebug) that setting individual layer size just don't adjust their respective canvas size: all the created canvases have the stage dimension!

This is not a problem with a small stage (at least with not too many layers), but with a huge stage and near a hundred layers wouldn't there be a performance issue ?

In other words, is this a wanted feature or a bug ?

Here is a simple test code :

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'main',
    width: 400,
    height: 400,
});
for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer({
        x:i*30+10,
        y:i*30+10,
        width:20,
        height:20,
    });
    layer.add( new Kinetic.Rect({
        width: 20,
        height: 20,
        fill: 'red',
    }));
    stage.add(layer);

    // trying to force layer dimensions
    layer.setWidth(20);
    layer.setHeight(20);
}
stage.draw();
```

And here, what I see when looking at the DOM :

```
<div id="main">
    <div style="position: relative; display: inline-block; width: 400px; height: 400px;" class="kineticjs-content">
        <canvas width="400" style="width: 400px; height: 400px; position: absolute;" height="400"></canvas>
        <canvas width="400" style="width: 400px; height: 400px; position: absolute;" height="400"></canvas>
        <canvas width="400" style="width: 400px; height: 400px; position: absolute;" height="400"></canvas>
        <canvas width="400" style="width: 400px; height: 400px; position: absolute;" height="400"></canvas>
        <canvas width="400" style="width: 400px; height: 400px; position: absolute;" height="400"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes, you can’t control the size of a layer’s canvas**

And yes, you will get a big performance hit with hundreds of layers (= hundreds of full-sized canvases).

Layers are always the same size as their stage—even if you set a lesser width/height.  The width/height properties are inherited from Kinetic.Node and appear to be ineffective.

Also a layer with a fixed width will allow a shape to “bleed” out of that layer (the shape will not be clipped into that layer).

So…layers created **in moderation** are great for:

- layering objects that require similar redraw schedules,
- z-indexing,
- redraw performance benefits.

Eric Rowell, KineticJS creator, did this stress test: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-drag-and-drop-stress-test-with-1000-shapes/

And he says this:

Create 10 layers each containing 1000 shapes to create 10,000 shapes.  This greatly improves performance because
only 1,000 shapes will have to be drawn at a time when a circle is removed from a layer rather than all 10,000 shapes.  Keep in mind that having too many layers can also slow down performance.  I found that using 10 layers each made up of 1,000 shapes performs better than 20 layers with 500 shapes or 5 layers with 2,000 shapes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it confirms what I thought ! I bet this limitation is done for other features to work correctly, although i'm sure performance could be increased by controlling smaller canvases, depending on one's precise project. I'll go with it then. Thanks